# Connection error for MongoDb replica-set using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to mongodb replica set running under 4 containers: 3 mongo as a cluster, and 1 to issue mongo commands to others.

Here I don't know how should I connect it to my application with a mongodb url.

`docker-compose.yml` is

```
mongo3:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: mongo3
  expose:
    - "27017"
    - "28017"
  restart: always

      entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs"]

mongo2:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: mongo2
  expose:
    - "27017"
    - "28017"
  restart: always
  entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs"]

mongo1:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: mongo1
  expose:
    - "27017"
    - "28017"
  links:
    - mongo2:mongo2
    - mongo3:mongo3
  restart: always
  entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs"]

mongosetup:
  image: mongo:latest
  links:
    - mongo1:mongo1
    - mongo2:mongo2
    - mongo3:mongo3
  volumes:
    - ./scripts:/scripts
    - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
    - ./data/dump:/dump

  restart: always
  entrypoint: [ "bash", "/scripts/mongo_setup.sh" ]

app:
  image: papagari/swoop.chat:latest
  environment:
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017/swoop?replicaSet=rs
    - ROOT_URL=https://localhost:3000
  links:
    - mongo1:mongo1
    - mongo2:mongo2
    - mongo3:mongo3
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
```

and `/scripts/mongo_setup.sh` is

```
MONGODB1=`ping -c 1 mongo1 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`
MONGODB2=`ping -c 1 mongo2 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`
MONGODB3=`ping -c 1 mongo3 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`    

echo "Waiting for startup.."
until curl http://${MONGODB1}:28017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done    

echo curl http://${MONGODB1}:28017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1
echo "Started.."    

sleep 10    

echo SETUP.sh time now: `date +"%T" `
mongo --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 <<EOF
   var cfg = {
        "_id": "rs",
        "version": 1,
        "members": [
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "host": "${MONGODB1}:27017",
                "priority": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "host": "${MONGODB2}:27017",
                "priority": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "host": "${MONGODB3}:27017",
                "priority": 0
            }
        ]
    };
    rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
    rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
    db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
EOF
```

Now I'm getting an error for `mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017/swoop?replicaSet=rs` 
Obviously `failed to connect to server` because the url I've used is not valid. I'm new to docker and mongo db replica set for the first time, trying to understand docker here. How it should work.

Error: `MongoError: no primary found in replicaset`.

Complete Error:

```
app_1        | 
app_1        | /app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
app_1        |                      throw(ex);
app_1        |                      ^
app_1        | MongoError: no primary found in replicaset
app_1        |     at Object.Future.wait (/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
app_1        |     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:216:27)
app_1        |     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
app_1        |     at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
app_1        |     at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
app_1        |     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:103:40)
app_1        |     at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
app_1        |     at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
app_1        |     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
app_1        |     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
app_1        |     - - - - -
app_1        |     at /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:631:32
app_1        |     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:421:24)
app_1        |     at [object Object].g (events.js:260:16)
app_1        |     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
app_1        |     at [object Object].emit (events.js:169:7)
app_1        |     at /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:283:14
app_1        |     at /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:436:18
app_1        |     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
app_1        |     at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

I've searched many placed all I got is with local machine or the server machine not with docker links.

**Update**
response of `rs.status()` in mongo1 container, which look pretty fine, primary and secondary are initialized properly.

```
{
    "set" : "rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:31:10.861Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "172.17.0.4:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 62,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1476858630, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:30:30Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1476858629, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:30:29Z"),
            "configVersion" : 13918,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "172.17.0.3:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 51,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1476858630, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:30:30Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:31:09.633Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:31:10.291Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "syncingTo" : "172.17.0.2:27017",
            "configVersion" : 13918
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "172.17.0.2:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 51,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1476858630, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:30:30Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:31:09.633Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-10-19T06:31:09.283Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "syncingTo" : "172.17.0.4:27017",
            "configVersion" : 13918
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Any tips will be helpful. TIA

Comment: Do a `docker exec -it mongosetup bash` (replace mongosetup for the container real name in `docker ps`. The `cat /etc/hosts` check that the ips are correctly there. Also `ping mongo1`

Comment: I'm getting ping  response from mongo1

Comment: `cat /etc/hosts`  have this, 
```172.17.0.4 mongo1_1 mongo1 mongocluster_mongo1_1  
    172.17.0.4 mongocluster_mongo1_1 mongo1  
    172.17.0.3 mongocluster_mongo2_1 mongo2
    172.17.0.2 mongo3 mongo3 mongocluster_mongo3_1
    172.17.0.2 mongo3_1 mongo3 mongocluster_mongo3_1
    172.17.0.2 mongocluster_mongo3_1 mongo3
    172.17.0.4 mongo1 mongo1 mongocluster_mongo1_1
    172.17.0.3 mongo2_1 mongo2 mongocluster_mongo2_1
    172.17.0.3 mongo2 mongo2 mongocluster_mongo2_1
    172.17.0.5 ab02e918d3e4```

Comment: Well apparently your docker configuration is working. I think can be a problem with mongodb configuration. Let's wait for a mongodb expert to appear.

Comment: thanks @CarlosRafaelRamirez

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: You can run `docker exec -it mongo1 mongo`  and then `rs.status() ` it should show what is wrong about the replica set. You can put the output here if you dont know how to fix it

Comment: @andresk I've added the response in question.

Comment: this seems an issue with timing, may when mongo containers are initializing, It may concurrently it might be assigning app container as well.

Comment: It's not good practice to include the replica set initiation / configuration in the docker container startup routine, because it is a one-off data job. Instead, the recommended way to do it is to let each mongod container start up normally, then *manually* do the replica set configuration and so on. See https://medium.com/@gargar454/deploy-a-mongodb-cluster-in-steps-9-using-docker-49205e231319#.iectcgcbj for a detailed guide.

Comment: @VinceBowdren how you'll manage if in case your server fail or restarted, you must have to do all these process again.

Comment: @ankibalyan Once the replica set is initiated and the hosts are attached, any mongodb server will automatically rejoin the replicaset when it is restarted.

Comment: Thanks @VinceBowdren for valuable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said on the comments, as you replicaSet configuration is alright, probably your `app` is starting along with the others and before the replicaSet is configured, it breaks.

You could try using [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dependson) on the app configuration, that will make the `app` container start after the others. But be aware that this might not work because it [waits until the container is ready and not until the replicaSet is configured](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

If this doesn't work I think the easiest way is to start `app` separately after running docker-compose.

Comment: I've written two upstart script, 1st one will start the mongo cluster, and the other one will start the app which start once the mongo cluster script is executed.

Comment: Which gives me error 3-4 times initially as `Primary not found`, but after that couple of restarts it is working fine.

Comment: probably  `depends_on` and container ready may be better solution. I'll try with that. 
Thanks @andresk